# Saving variable of a row in localstorage onclick

Tags: jquery, ajax, local-storage

I have some textfields which are nested and have a class called `"names"`. Close to each textfield is a link "view details" with a class called `"view details"`.

I want to achieve something like `onclick` of a particular view details on a row, I want to save the value in the textfield in localstorage

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.view details').on('click', function(event) {
        localStorage.setItem('name', $('.names').val());
    });
});
```

here's a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4dL6jdr/

Comment: Show the relavant html  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector could not select view detail so remove space. *$('.view details')* change to  *$('.view.details')*

```
$('.view.details').on('click', function (event) {
    var inputElemnet = $(this).closest('tr').find('.names');
    localStorage.setItem(inputElemnet.attr('name'), inputElemnet.val());
   // console.log(localStorage.getItem(inputElemnet.attr('name')));

});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4dL6jdr/2/)**

Comment: show you html code or make sample in fiddle , with out ur html we could not give exact solution for you , these are all assumption

Comment: Now check just before i updated with current text box name not index